# get value from function in exported function JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

today I'm working on a project in JavaScript. I've an exported function A that is in an other file then my location.js. When I click I get the location of an user.

But how do I get the values from a function in an exported function?

I need the coordinates in the function.

Code:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                function(position) {
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    long = position.coords.longitude;
                    coordinates = {
                        latitude: lat,
                        longitude: long
                    };
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(coordinates));
                    return coordinates;
                }, {
                   (errorHandling)
                }};
```

Could someone help me out?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: The issue here would be to supply an async result. which is the exported function and which is the user function.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Can you maybe out with that? where to apply async? And how to include?

Comment: Please share the entire function and how its used

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri https://jsfiddle.net/y8d25r4z/ here I've a link, but its in ReactJs and I've a function named getLocation()

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an async function which works on callback principle and not promises.

In order to get the returned values, you either need to convert it into a promise based function or pass a callback function to it which you call when data is available like

```
const getLocation = (callback) => {
    ....

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function myLocation(position) {
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                long = position.coords.longitude;
                callback({
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: long
                }); // the callback method
            },
            function(error) {
                ...
            }
        );
    } 
    ...
};

module.exports = { getLocation };
```

Now you can call the function and set the coordinates in state of react like

```
import Button from './button.js';

import { getLocation } from './functions/getLocation.js';

class Card extends React.Component {
    state = {
       coordinates: {}
    }
    getLocationCoordinates = () => {
        getLocation((coordinates) => {
            this.setState({coordinates})
        })
    }
    render() {
        const { lat, lng } = this.state.coordinates;
        return (
            <div id={'location'} className={'card'}>
                    ...
                    <Button function={this.getLocationCoordinates} text={'Allow Location'} />
                    ...
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Card;
```